# Login to Instagram with WebRequest programmatically

Tags: c#, http, authentication, https, request

#### Problem

I want to send **login** **requests** to the **Instagram** **server** to be able to **login** as a user, but don't know how.

---

#### Source Code

```
using System;

namespace WebRequests
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Net.CookieContainer myCookies = new System.Net.CookieContainer();
            Console.Write("Enter the username: ");
            string username = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.Write("Enter the password: ");
            string password = Console.ReadLine();

            string postData = "username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&security_level=0&form=submit";

            bool result = HttpMethods.Post("https://instagram.com/", postData, "https://instagram.com", myCookies);
            if (result)
                Console.WriteLine("Valid!");
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid!");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That will not work because a variety of reason:

1. Instagram uses Crsf token, which you are not sending in the post request you are making. Among other headers that you are also not using.
2. The second reason which is the most important one, the parameters that are sent in the POST request to instagram are 4 (username, enc_password, queryParams, optIntoOneTap). While you can get away with username, queryParams and optIntoOneTap. You cannot (you can but is really hard to do it), convert your password to the enc_password that they re making. The only way to achieve this would be to analyze the instagram code with the dev tools.

Your best bet would be to emulate a web browser that supports javascript, and try to fire the onClick event

Answer (score 0):

You can use [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/downloads/) to open up a browser session and simulate user behavior of performing a login action. To get the user session and maintain it for programmatic actions, you might want to grab things like cookie, csrfToken or JWT tokens, whatever instagram uses.

While performing the requests programmatically, you might want to provide most headers that a normal browser would provide, else instagram servers won't accept the request and might turn them down. Things to include are (but not limited to) `User-Agent`, `Referer`, `x-csrftoken` etc

However, if you want to take the API route, you might want to implement Facebook login as suggested in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/overview#authentication)